Extracting bits from random event unbiased
I have a number $Y$, from a random event that can give $X$ number of possible outcomes, (say $100$).
Shannon's entropy tells us we have $log2(100) \approx 6.6$ bits of entropy.
Is there any way I can extract these $6$ bits without introducing any bias of the remaining $\approx 0.6$ bits?
I'm looking for some math function that can clamp/normalize the outcome, for example I can modulo the result to $2^6$ to get exactly $6$ bits, but the remaining $0.6$ bits will bias the result towards the lower numbers, so that won't work.
That is, for all possible values $Y in [0..99]$



$Y \rightarrow Y \mod 2^6$




$0 \rightarrow 0$ (000000)


$1 \rightarrow 1$ (000001)


$2 \rightarrow 2$ (000010)


...


$63 \rightarrow 63$ (111111)


$64 \rightarrow 0$ (000000)


$65 \rightarrow 1$ (000001)


...


$99 \rightarrow 35$ (100011)



When $Y >= 64$, numbers $0-35$ (bits 000000-100011) are more likely to occur.

Using rejection sampling you can extract $6$ bits from $1$ event. (just ignore the event if it's larger than $63$). Without rejection sampling, you can only get $2$ bits from an event (as $100$ is divisible by $2^2$). If you have $n$ trials of a random event, you would be able to extract up to  $\log_2(100)$ bits per event (on average), as $n$ goes to infinity. Eg. $1$ trial gives you only $6$ bits, but $2$ trials give you $13$ bits, as $100^2 > 2^{13}$, which gets you closer to your goal of $\approx 6.6$ bits per trial.

@user3257842 it seems impossible then without rejection sampling (inefficient) or taking the highest multiple of 2^x (also inefficient). In my case X is big, and sampling is infrequent and expensive task. However, a good middleground I found is to take a few bits less than the maximum, (5 bits instead of 6 for X = 100) then rejection sampling rate would only be 4% compared to 36%. When X is very large and few bits are taken off, rejection sampling becomes improbable <0.01%.

I take it you can’t save information from one (infrequent) sample to the next?

If your event is a number from $[0,99]$, we know that 100 = 64 + 32 +4.
Our aim is to extract as many bits as we can from that. A roll will give us:
$6$ bits with a  probability $64/100$  (if the number is between $0$ and $64$) or $5$ bits with probability $32/100$ or (if the number is between $64$ or $96$) or $2$ bits with probability $4/100$ (if the number is between $96$ or $100$). So getting the most bits is the highest probability. But the length of our output also contains information we can use to get more.

Assume we run it two times and get a total of $6+6 = 12$ bits. Then we attach $0$ as an extra bit to have $13$. Assume we had gotten $6 + 5$ bits as our $2$ trials. Then we attach "01" as extra bits. Assume instead we had gotten $5 + 6$ bits. Then we can attach "11" as extra bits. The probabilities balance so that from these $3$ cases (ignoring the rest where we get less than 11 bits), we've constructed 13 uniformly distributed bits. Which is the best we can do for 2 trials. I think something related to prefix codes/huffman coding/source coding theorem can help in making a general algorithm.

@user3257842 I cannot save information or run it twice, as I need to discard previous runs. Next best is a low probability of rejecting the sample <1%. I am looking at different/higher X values but don't have control of the exact number as it occurs naturally. I hoped I could capture some entropy without rejection. Best I can do is reduce probability. Say X=1,000,000, then 6 bits = no rejection, because X is a multiple of 2^6 (but too much lost bits). 19 bits = highest rejection (48%), and reducing rejection rate for decreasing bits: (18, 17, 16) = (21.4%, 8.2%, 1.7%) respectively.

@user3257842 prefix codes/huffman coding won't work, as they may form a bias for more 0's or 1's, it doesn't guarantee equal amount of 0's and 1's as using the full bit-space would guarantee.

@joriki that's correct, I cannot. I was hoping for a nicer solution. Reducing the probability of rejecting the whole sample, might be the only way.

It can work if the amount of bits you extract from a trial is allowed to be variable. Ie. Let's take your $x = 1000000$ example. In binary we get: $1000000=2^{19}+2^{18}+2^{17}+2^{16}+2^{14}+2^{9}+2^{6}$. So we have a probability of $\frac{2^{19}}{10^6} \approx 0.52$ to get  $19$ unbiased bits, a probability of $\frac{2^{18}}{10^6} \approx 0.26$ to get $18$ unbiased bits, a probability of  $\frac{2^{17}}{10^6} \approx 0.13$ to get $17$ unbiased bits, etc. With this scheme we don't know how many bits we will get , but we still extract more information than naive rejection sampling.

Huffman coding is then used to extract more unbiased bits from the length of our results, during repeated trials.

@user3257842 Huffman is biased as mentioned. With the previous example X=100, you have a 0.64 chance of your 13th bit being a 0 bit (in the 6+6 case), so not 50/50. Back to X=10^6, if we sacrifice our 19 bits for a fixed 16 bits and wrap the code. We will have each 16 bits occur 15 (or 16 times) over the 10^6, that is (10^(6))/(2^(16))=15.2. The more we wrap multiple times by using lesser bits, the bias reduces, but it won't be completely unbiased either. Either you have a low probability of rejection, or you take that lower probability to reduce bias and decide to reject or keep biased value.

In my example of two rolls of "100" , the $13$'th bit is $0$ iff you can extract $6$ bits out of both rolls. That gives $(\frac{64}{100})^2 =   0.4096$ probability.  It is $1$ if one of the two rolls gives $5$ bits, while the other gives $6$, giving a probability $(\frac{32}{100})(\frac{64}{100})+(\frac{64}{100})(\frac{32}{100}) =   0.4096$ to be $1$. In the remaining cases it is considered yet underived. So it can't always be derived out of $2$ rolls (prob $0.8192$), but when it is derived , it's unbiased.

If you want to do it exactly, without losing any information, you should resort to binary arithmetic coding.
In your case, we the unit $[0,1]$ interval divided in $n=100$ intervals of length $1/100$. We assume that the first value of $Y$ gives as one of these intervals. And, further, this interval is again subdivided into $n=100$ subintervals, and the second value of $Y$ selects the corresponding one. And so on.
Now, after $m$ ocurrerences of $Y$, we'll have an interval of length $l=1/100^m$. Now, the same interated division of the unit interval, but now in half. These dyadic intervals are characterized by a binary fractional representation that coincides in the first $k$ binary digits. Find the smallest dyadic interval covers  the other interval  It's easy to show that the length of this interval is at most $ 2 1/100^m$, and the $k \approx  m \log_2 100$ bits are equiprobable.
If you want something simpler, you can extend the rejection schema:
For $n=100$, we can choose the extension $m=11$, because $\log_2 100^{11} = 73.082$ (not so far from the truncation). We then produce $73$ bits using $11$ numbers, with a success probability of $2^{73}/100^{11} \approx 0.9444
7$, which gives an average tries of $11.6467$ numbers, that is, an average efficiency of $73/11.6467 = 6.26787$ bits per number, not far from the optimal $\log_2 100  = 6.64386$.
